# What does my printer mean when he says '$1.50 for a 30" running edge'?

Tags: print-design, terminology

We are printing some photos to be mounted for the office and I am assuming it has something to do with the photos being printed on rolls instead of sheets? This was his reply when we asked for his pricing.

Comment: I believe 'running edge' is a synonym for 'full bleed' meaning the image is printed all the way to the edge of the paper. I assume there's a $1.50 up charge for this?

Comment: @DA01 seems like you solved the problem here :) Perhaps post as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The printer is likely referring to the price of plotting at his facility. A plotter is a large format printer that uses rolls of paper instead of sheets. When I last plotted an oversized image at FedEx Office, they charged about $1.50 per inch and their plotter was 44 inches wide.

Extrapolating from that, it sounds like the printer is saying your images can be up to 30 inches wide, and cost $1.50 per every inch in height.